# Grouping by more than one column ag grid

Tags: angular, ag-grid

There are 4 columns in my ag-grid table, they are price, organization, country and products. I want to group them such as the key for the group is `price + country`. How can I do that in ag-grid?

I will give a sample grouping :

Price       country                      org              Product

+.  12          IND

```
12          IND                          A                 P1
12          IND                          B                 P2
```

If we click on the '+' button, the following rows should be displayed like that.

Please let me know if anyone has any clue regarding this. Any help would be appreciated.

Example 2.

Grouped Row header

```
Country              Price                Org            Product
```

- ```
   IND                 4
  ```

Above is the grouped row header, common values should be in their respective column and other values should be blank. And when we click on that expand button, following should be the result:

```
Country              Price                 Org            Product
```

- ```
   IND                  4
   IND                  4                   O1               P1
   IND                  4                   O1               P2
   IND                  4                   O2               P3
  ```

Answer (score -1):

You could create an extra field which contains the price and the country, and use that field to group.

Add the following into your column definitions:

```
  {
    field: 'groupField',
    valueGetter: params => {
      if (params.data)
      {
        return params.data.country + params.data.price;
      }
    },
    rowGroup: true
  },
```

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/7wJVATl5ccUOiY98).

Comment: When the rows are grouped according to price and country, the group row header should country and price value in their respective column and all other values should be blank. And then when we click on the + ( expand ) button. the values should be displayed. I will add another example